# How to grep for a pattern in multiple files while excluding commented lines

Tags: regex, grep

I have a bunch of LaTeX files that I want to search using `grep pattern *.tex -n --color=always`. It's important that I see:

1. The file's name that matched
2. The line number of the match
3. The full line, with the matched pattern highlighted

Furthermore, sometimes the pattern needs to be a full word match, so the command becomes `grep pattern *.tex -n -w --color=always`

I would like to modify this command to exclude commented lines in my `*.tex` files, which start with the `%` character. I am not interested in matches in comments.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try the following command:

```
grep -n -v --color=always '^%' *.tex | grep content
```

EXPLANATION

- The first `grep` invocation excludes (`-v`) line starting with `%` (regex `^%` matches `%` at the start of the line (`^`))
- The output of the first `grep` invocation is passed as input to the second `grep` invocation
- The second `grep` invocations includes only rows matching with your filter pattern (you can add `-w` option if you need it).

I hope this can help you!

Comment: Oh... silly me. I thought that would mess up the highlighting, but it seems to work fine. The only potential problem one might have with it is that it also matches in the *.tex file names, no? This is okay for my use case though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Would this do? First some test stuff:

```
$ cat file
yes
no % yes commented out
yes % yes before comment
no
noyes
furthermore yes
furthermore yes% yes
furthermore no% yes
```

The grep:

```
$ grep -Hn "^[^%]*\(^\| \)yes\( \|$\|%\)" file
file:1:yes
file:3:yes % yes before comment
file:6:furthermore yes
file:7:furthermore yes% yes
```

**Edit**: For partial matches:

```
$ grep -Hn "^[^%]*yes" file
```

and to highlight only the search word you need to grep for it again:

```
$ grep -Hn "^[^%]*yes" file | grep yes
file:1:yes
file:3:yes % yes before comment
file:5:noyes
file:6:furthermore yes
file:7:furthermore yes% yes
```

Comment: Thank you! This is on the right track, but it does not display the match correctly: it starts highlighting the match at the beginning of the line when using `--color=always'. Also, is there a way to match partially? (e.g., can I get it to match 'noyes'?)